# Should I append '[]' to multiple html checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically generate markup for a data structure using JavaScript, so that it can be sent to an arbitrary server via submit.

As I understand it, this is valid HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit_data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Ape" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Snake" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send data">
</form>
```

But it seems that some servers (for example PHP based?) can deal better with a list when the name is followed by a pair of square brackets:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit_data">
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Ape" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Snake" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send data">
</form>
```

What is the difference, when this data is sent to servers (PHP based or not)?

Comment: If checkboxes hold the same name, yes do include the brackets. Then you'd use a `foreach` to extract/seperate the values. Otherwise, use radio buttons if you only want users to choose from one option.

Comment: Ape would be overwritten by Snake if it was checked, so yes you should use an array. Because you cant hold multiple values in the same string variable. *unless it get json encoded before ect.*

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: Incorrect. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: @FelixKling whats Incorrect about my comment?

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: Eh, you edited your comment, I forgot what exactly you wrote. But it sounded like you are saying you can't use the same name multiple times. Of course you can, but PHP needs the `[]` to understand that the values should be treated as array.

Comment: No im saying *How would PHP be able to access animal as an array like* `?animal=Ape&animal=Snake`, you cant PHP would only see Snake.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: Yes, that's true.  Either way, the link is useful ;)

Comment: So its not Incorrect then? ;p

Comment: 'Ape would be overwritten by Snake ...': do you mean it will not be sent by the browser, or discarde by PHP? Note that this question is not limited to PHP.

Comment: @mar10: PHP can't handle fields with the same name, unless the name uses this array notation. Other languages will work just fine. The browser will send `?animal=Ape&animal=Snake`

Comment: @mar10 Yes its sent by browser, not discarded by PHP, the value just overwritten, said that..

Comment: @FelixKling: could you elaborate this as answer? sounds like what I was asking for (together with your 'Most languages to this without the []')

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP, then yes you should append `[]` to the name when you expect these values to be part of a list, at least when using `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Strictly speaking, however, `animal[]` is no different than `animal`. Both are keys, and square brackets are not special in the query string format. If you are using a different server backend it is possible to handle multiple values of `animal`. Both values are sent by the browser:

```
animal=Ape&animal=Snake
```

In PHP it is possible, however, to parse multiple values of `animal` in PHP as well. The `$_GET` and `$_POST` globals are for convenience. They follow the same rules as the [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function, which has some quirks like periods `.` being converted to underscores `_`.

You can get the raw GET query with:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

And you can get the raw POST data with:

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

The creation of `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals are regulated with the [variables_order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) setting in php.ini. These are created only when you use them, as long as [auto_globals_jit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit) is enabled (otherwise it always happens just before the script runs). As long as auto_globals_jit is enabled you can use the raw data without the extra overhead.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, because it nicely explains PHP behavior. However, since my question was not limited to PHP, I tried to summarize comments in my own answer, and wait a bit for objections.

Comment: @mar10 To be fair, you do have a `php` tag in your post. I revised my answer a bit. The point I'm making is it doesn't matter what server backend you are using. It will work fine, even in PHP. The `$_POST` global is for convenience. There are other ways of parsing POST data, even in PHP.

Comment: sorry if the tag was misleading, i removed it (and edited the question a bit to clarify the use case)

Answer (score 0):

You should either use different names or use the square brackets (which will basically create an array of the values).

If you use the same name for multiple inputs, PHP will only be able to handle the last one.

Radio buttons are an exception as there you can only make one selection thus only one value will be needed.

Comment: well, didn't see it, sorry... why is an answer added as a comment anyway?

Comment: what are you implying, that I was copying it, you are not, right? why do you use comment if it's an answer?

Comment: FYI, if you use `foo[]` multiple times, you also have the same name for multiple inputs. It's just an indication for PHP to treat the values as array. Most languages to this without the `[]`.

Comment: @FelixKling not sure i understand that, or i misunderstood the way this is done... i thought if you use the square brackets, it will create new key => value pairs each time you use them in the form, if you specify a key, it will make it an associative array, otherwise it will just numbered starting with 0...

Comment: I'm not implying anything. Had I posted my comment as an answer, my peers would've most likely downvoted it because it's fit to be a comment. So, I chose not to on those grounds. Once you get to higher rep points, you'll see what I mean. ;-) SO's weird that way.

Comment: hm... why is it not an answer...?

Comment: The `[]` syntax has **nothing** to do with HTML. There is no difference between `foo` or `foo[]` for HTML. It's just a name. PHP treats names with `[]` differently. That's all.

Comment: @FelixKling good info, thanks, though i'm not sure if i'm contradicting to that in my answer or comment, am i?

Comment: You said *"If you use the same name for multiple inputs, only the last one will be sent"* which is not true. Both values will be send, but PHP can only handle them if the name ends with `[]`. Other languages don't have that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks to every one who commented or posted answers. Alas, most responses were targeted at PHP scenarios, which is not my main concern. @FelixKling added some helpful comments that I pick up here (Felix, if you choose to post an answer, I will remove mine and accept yours).*

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html):

> Multiple controls can have the same name; for example, here we give all the checkboxes the same name, and the server distinguishes which checkbox was checked by seeing which values are submitted with that name — like the radio buttons, they are also given unique values with the value attribute.

So using `name="animal"` and `name="animal[]"` are both valid and will send multiple entries to the server: `animal=Ape&animal=Snake` or `animal[]=Ape&animal[]=Snake` respectively.

In general servers can process both variants.

**If, however** the server is implemented using PHP, the latter syntax (with trailing `[]`) is required, because otherwise PHP will discard all but the last entry.

So my conclusion is: use the plain syntax, unless you have a PHP backend (or if the backend has similar behavior).